# About the 'experimental' of 'Changed in version 1.4: Index key for glossary term should be considered experimental'

Tags: python-sphinx

#### question

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html

About the 'experimental' of 'Changed in version 1.4: Index key for glossary term should be considered experimental.'

- What puts index key on 'experimental'?

#### confirmed

Editing glossary with index key, 'make clean' was needed before 'make html'. Or, the index key disappeared from genindex.html.

I guess that all of the follwing testcase shuold be passed. the first testcase is related with 'make clean'. They are passed at all, on a new indexer.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import unittest
from sphinx.environment.adapters.indexentries import IndexEntries

testcase01i = {
'doc1': [
    ('single', 'aaa', 'id-111', '', 'clf1'),
    ('single', 'bbb', 'id-112', '', None),
],
'doc2': [
    ('single', 'aaa', 'id-121', '', None),
    ('single', 'bbb', 'id-122', '', 'clf2'),
], }

testcase01o = [
('clf1',
  [('aaa', [[('', 'doc1.html#id-111'), ('', 'doc2.html#id-121')], [], 'clf1']), ]
),
('clf2',
  [('bbb', [[('', 'doc1.html#id-112'), ('', 'doc2.html#id-122')], [], None]), ]
),
]

testcase02i = {
'doc1': [
    ('see','hogehoge; foo','id-211','main',None),
    ('seealso','hogehoge; bar','id-212','main',None), ]
}

testcase02o = [
('H',
    [('hogehoge',
        [[],
         [('see also bar', []), ('see foo', [])],
         None
        ])
    ])
]

testcase03i = {
'doc1': [
    ('single','func1() (aaa module)','id-311','',None),
    ('single','func1() (bbb module)','id-312','',None),
    ('single','func1() (ccc module)','id-313','',None),]
}

testcase03o = [
('F',
  [('func1()',
    [[],
     [('(aaa module)', [('', 'doc1.html#id-311')]),
      ('(bbb module)', [('', 'doc1.html#id-312')]),
      ('(ccc module)', [('', 'doc1.html#id-313')])
     ],
     None])])
]


testcase04i = {
'doc1': [
    ('single','func1() (aaa module)','id-411','',None),
    ('single','func1() (bbb module)','id-412','',None),
    ('single','func1() (ccc module)','id-413','main',None), ]
}

testcase04o = [
('F',
  [('func1()',
    [[],
     [('(aaa module)', [('', 'doc1.html#id-411')]),
      ('(bbb module)', [('', 'doc1.html#id-412')]),
      ('(ccc module)', [('main', 'doc1.html#id-413')]), ],
     None])])
]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

class _domain(object):
    def __init__(self, entries):
        self.entries = entries

class _env(object):
    def __init__(self, domain):
        self.domain = {}
        self.domain['index'] = domain
    def get_domain(self, domain_type):
        return self.domain[domain_type]

class _builder(object):
    def get_relative_uri(self, uri_type, file_name):
        return f'{file_name}.html'

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

bld = _builder()

class TestcaseIndexEntries(unittest.TestCase):
    def test01_classifier(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        dmn = _domain(testcase01i)
        env = _env(dmn)
        gidx = IndexEntries(env).create_index(bld)
        self.assertEqual(testcase01o, gidx)
    def test02_see_and_seealso(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        dmn = _domain(testcase02i)
        env = _env(dmn)
        gidx = IndexEntries(env).create_index(bld)
        self.assertEqual(testcase02o, gidx)
    def test03_homonymous_function(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        dmn = _domain(testcase03i)
        env = _env(dmn)
        gidx = IndexEntries(env).create_index(bld)
        self.assertEqual(testcase03o, gidx)
    def test04_homonymous_function(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        dmn = _domain(testcase04i)
        env = _env(dmn)
        gidx = IndexEntries(env).create_index(bld)
        self.assertEqual(testcase04o, gidx)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

#### purpose

I want to know which there is some other puting index key on 'experimental'. If there is it, I want to see if it is fixed by the indexer.

#### note

I am writing this using a translation software. If there is anything difficult to understand, I will add it.

Comment: Hello, `index` in Python Sphinx is currently a very difficult directive to use - in my experience. There are some bugs [see this thread for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66229133). If you search the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues) you'll find in one of the last versions (before [Sphinx 3.5](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html)) the index was significantly improved overall. However I still think the index lacks flexibility and it's easier to adapt yourself to how it works instead of trying to fight it.

Comment: If you look at the 3rd example in [glossary](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-glossary) what means `term 1 : A` is `“term : key”`. (I would have to check my code to confirm this), but what I remember happened is a reference is introduced in the genindex with `key`.

Comment: My solution was to avoid this, I simply introduced the glossary terms into the index using [the index directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#index-generating-markup) and used [cross-references](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) to them when I wanted. Meaning the glossary (you can have several) and the index (there is only one) were kept separate. So it wasn't fully automated, but it was easier to write and maintain overall.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write three comments. I'm reading what you wrote.

Comment: (about your first comment) I found [#8904](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8904). I putted on a comment, because I might know what function the problem depends on. althogh I don't guess that a sphinx extention which I made has a same problem like that, I will add a testcase for checking the problem.

Comment: I forgot to say, if you then want to reference a glossary term somewhere in the documentation use the [`term`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-term) role. That's the easiest way to get things working. (My documentation was bilingual, so I wrote 3 glossaries one in each language and one with 2 languages grouped per term. It's not ideal but it worked.)

Comment: (about your 4th comment) thanks for what you give. It found that the sphinx extention have to be taken case of `:term:`.

Comment: I created [#9744](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9744). Thanks to the thread you gave me, I realized that I might as well register it on github. Thank you.